# SwiftUI: Expand LazyVGrid cells to max height of each row

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, lazyvgrid

I'm using a `LazyVGrid` in a `ScrollView` to display cells in either a 1 (portrait) or 2 (landscape) column layout. However, the height of shorter cells in a row does not expand to match the taller cell in the same row and looks pretty terrible.

How can I ensure the height is always the same for every cell in a row? Obviously I don't want a fixed height for every cell. (To be clear, I want "Church - Eastbound" to be as tall as "Church & Market" and "West Portal" to be as tall as "Forest Hill".

```
ScrollView(.vertical) {
    LazyVGrid(
        columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 400))],
        alignment: .leading,
        spacing: 16
    ) {
        ForEach(sharedFavorites.favoriteStops.indices, id: \.self) { index in
            let favorite = sharedFavorites.favoriteStops[index]
            
            NavigationLink(
                destination: SingleStationView(
                    station: favorite.station,
                    direction: favorite.direction
                )
            ) {
                BoardRow(favorite: favorite, stop: favorite.observableStop)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color(.secondarySystemGroupedBackground))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: 2-column grid. In each row, the cells are centered vertically, resulting in empty space above and below the shorter cell.]

I tried `.frame(maxHeight: .infinity)` on both the `BoardRow` view and the inner contents of `BoardView` (which is just a normal `VStack`). It didn't work.

Comment: You want to set a concrete height for the cell. Try 150-200

Comment: I explicitly don't want to do this, though, since each row can be a different height.

Comment: There is no other way, explicitly or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You were really close — just needed to put the `.frame(maxHeight:)` before `.background`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            LazyVGrid(
                columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 160))],
                alignment: .leading,
                spacing: 16
            ) {
                ForEach([0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 3], id: \.self) { index in

                    BoardCell(index: index)
                        .padding()
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
                        .background(Color(.secondarySystemGroupedBackground)) /// `background` goes after the frame!
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                }
            }
            .padding(20)
        }
        .background(Color(.secondaryLabel))
    }
}

/// I recreated your view for testing purposes
struct BoardCell: View {
    var index: Int

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Powell (Westbound)")

            ForEach(0 ..< index) { _ in
                HStack {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(.green)
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)

                    Text("4")

                    Text("19")

                    Text("17")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: 2-column grid. In each row, cells share the height of the tallest cell. Inner content is aligned to the top-left edge.]

Comment: Thanks for going above and beyond here with this example! Unfortunately this didn't work for me, I copy-pasted your code into Xcode and the result is this: ![screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/gWSpoba.png) . I'm wondering if this behavior is different on iOS 15 vs 16? I'm currently using Xcode 13 still

Comment: Hmm, possibly. I'm on iOS 16

Comment: I'm experimenting kind of the same problem. While in iOS 16 works as expected, in 15 the cells are shrinking to its content in the same way as your example.